# Setting a variable

Tags: sql

Well I have a few questions and I like to make sure I am understanding what I am doing. So here it is I am working on a project and I am suppose to Create a variable called MinOrder and populate it with the smallest line item amount after discount for the Northwind CustomerNo ‘ALFKI’ (Careful: we’re dealing with currency here, so don’t just assume you’re going to use an int.) Output the final value of MinOrder. Now this is what I have:

```
   Use Northwind
Declare @MinOrder money;
Set @MinOrder = (Select MIN(UnitPrice) From [Order Details]);
Select @MinOrder
```

I notice that I didn't put in the ALFKI. Well I seen it said not use really use the int. I went and declare the minorder because it does with a variable and then I am taking that variable using it for the unitprice even though it says discount but when I try to put discount there it showed a red error. I am wounder if I should use another set to do the customerId = ALFKI or if I can throw it into this code. I know my code might be way off but thats why I am posting it so I can have an understanding when it comes to this only because it is a part of programming. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @MinOrder = SELECT MIN(UnitPrice)
                  FROM [Order Details]
                 WHERE CustomerNumber = 'ALFKI'
```

Replace `CustomerNumber` with the name of the customer number field.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @MinOrder = MIN(UnitPrice)
  FROM [Order Details] od
       INNER JOIN Orders o
          ON o.order_ID = od.order_ID
       INNER JOIN Cusomers c
          ON c.customer_ID = o.customer_ID
 WHERE c.customer_code = 'ALFKI';
```